# Testing which includes calls to remote services

Tags: java, web-services, unit-testing, testing, junit

I'm looking to test code where the results of a call to a remote service are reflected in a local database after a period of time.

Can anyone advise on how I should go about doing this?

Here's the process:

A method utilises a web service to create an entity on a remote system. Once created the entity is fed back into the local system by means of a trickle feed (this is not part of the code to be tested). The test should then query the local database to ensure that the entity has been correctly created. A complication is that the time required for the local database to be updated with the entity is variable.

Any advice and suggestions welcomed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure exactly which part you want to test here. It seems you want to test the whole cycle, yet you don't want to test the code that copies the entity to the local DB? Could you clarify?

Comment: That's correct. I want to test that the entity has the correct attributes but I do not need to test the code which writes the entity to the local database. It's a case of 'is what is in the local database which we expected?'

Comment: @mip: *"is what is in the local database which we expected"* - that really sounds like you want to test whether your DB engine can do its job. Why is that? You never test such things - you unit test ORM mappings, query creation, information flow from your modules to DAL and that's where you stop. You assume DB can do its job.

Comment: @jimmy_keen I'm trying to test the processing which has taken place between the original web service call and entity being written to the local database. Sorry, I'm not doing a very good job of explaining this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are definitely doing an integration test. This is perfectly doable in JUnit, but you always need to know what exactly you are testing, and what you can test.

First, you need to know who controls the remote service. If it's you, great. If it's not you, watch out.

Let's assume that the remote service is not under your control. You're sending a request to the remote service, it is processing it, and sending a request to the local database. So you can't influence how long it will take, or how the data will be written to the local database, or what data transformation will take place.

So, all you can test is that some of the data that you're sending will end up in the database after a period of time. So, to test that **something** is happening, all you need to do is test that the appropriate line is in the database. This could be just a simple `SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE ...` [*]

If the remote system is stable, doesn't change often, then you could test more of the details of the lines in the local database, but remember that

1. you will have to update the test each time the remote service changes,
2. each time the remote service version changes, you have to add logic to your tests.

Remember, the place to test complicated application logic in the remote service is in the code for the remote service. Not your code.

Another thing to take into account:

**When testing someone elses code, things can change without notice, tests can fail without warning due to bugs in their code, their integration server being down, their database being down.** If possible, install their code on a machine which you control, this minimzes the number of problems of this type you'll have. Another alternative is to have a separate project
 specifically for these tests, so at least your builds will work if these tests fail.

If you have control over the remote service, great. Put your complicated logic tests in the tests for that service, and all you need in the local application is to test that some data comes back, a loopback test.

As for the actual test, a simple call of the remote service, and then a loop which tests for the existence of the data every 5 seconds or so would probably suffice. With a timeout of course. There isn't anything specific for the loop in JUnit, but have a look at the [Timeout](https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/rules/Timeout.java) @Rule for the Timeout.

[*] Along with appropriate error conditions of course.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you very much. Do you know of any examples of this sort of testing which may be useful for me to look at?

Answer (score 0):

> The test should then query the local database to ensure that the entity has been correctly created

Do you want to test whether DB engine can insert valid values..? I hope not. You shouldn't need querying database to test entity creation.

What you should test is whether your logic can produce those values correctly, or perhaps whether it can build proper `INSERT` command string. If that's the case, dependencies to service and actual DAO/DB related objects should be [faked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object).

In unit testing you want to focus on *single feature* (hence the name *unit* testing) at time. In this case I assume it would be proper entity/values creation. Testing whole process sounds more like an [integration test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing). Is that what you wanted to do?

Comment: Yes, this is probably classed as integration testing.